# Who are some examples of recent famous self-published authors?

Tags: creative-writing

What famous authors, within the last 40 years, were self-published?

Comment: would you please define the criteria you expect to be used for the term "Famous"?

Comment: Also, can you please tell us what would make one answer to this question better than another answer? If user X posts an answer listing five authors meeting the stated criteria, and user Y posts an answer listing five different authors also meeting the stated criteria, what might make one of these answers better or worse than the other?

Answer (score 6):

**Here's a list of nine writers who had exceptional success that all began when they self-published their first books (within the last 40 years):**

1. *Wool Trilogy* by Hugh Howey (sold to Simon & Schuster for $.5M)
2. *Still Alice* by Lisa Genova (made into a film starring Julianne Moore)
3. *The Celestine Prophecy* by James Redfield (translated into 34 languages)
4. *Riyria Chronicles* by Michael J. Sullivan (followup was sold for over $100K)
5. *The Wealthy Barber* by David Chilton (bestseller in Canada)
6. *Ten Tiny Breaths* by K.A. Tucker (led to a successful career)
7. *Damaged* by H.M. Ward (start of a series with 4M copies sold)
8. *My Blood Approves* series by Amanda Hocking (made $2M on eBook sales alone)
9. *Fifty Shades of Grey* by EL James (worldwide bestseller, made into three movies that have grossed a combined total of over $1.5B).

Additional notes on what makes each of the books/authors successful/famous are included in the link below.

Source: [10 Self-Published Authors Who Made it Big](https://www.bookstr.com/10-self-published-authors-who-made-it-big).

Comment: Who are any of these people? They my have gotten rich but that doesn't mean they got famous, or left a lasting impression.

Comment: @ChrisSunami On you perhaps, _50 Shades_ I know only as "that BS" as described by others who actually know what it is, I couldn't tell you what it's about, nor who wrote it. Nor can I tell you what either EL James or James Redfield have written without Googling more than I care to, that goes for everyone on the list too.

Comment: @ChrisSunami What was made into a movie? As for the rhetorical question part don't worry about that I'm killing time until I get sleepy so this is fun, even if I am more than half serious.

Comment: @Ash https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifty_Shades_(film_series) "Worldwide, the series has grossed $1.320 billion, making it the fourth highest-grossing R-rated franchise of all-time." // Robert - you might want to edit into your answer a brief note on why these books are considered successful.

Comment: @ChrisSunami Wow someone is making entirely too much money given I have heard _50 Shades_ described as "the worst Twilight fanfic ever written" more than once.

Comment: @Chris - thanks, I've added a line to explain where notes can be found.

Comment: @Ash I have to agree with Chris, the OP didn't ask if the books were any good or made a lasting impression, just whether the authors were famous and E.L. James is certainly that. As for the others, I guess it depends on your definition of fame, but I've certainly *heard* of these other authors even though I haven't read all of these books. And Still Alice made a lasting impression on a lot of people, either through the book or the film starring Julianne Moore. Sorry, I have to ask, but where have you *been* for the last ten years???  :)

Comment: @GGx E.L. James' work may be famous although I'm still not clear on what s/he? wrote, but the name rings no bells of any kind. As far as where I've been, I'm an almost pure Sci-fi/Fantasy reader with a bent for A. apocalypse fiction and B. the classics, the only writers I even read much of who have published anything this century are, in no particular order, S.M. Stirling, Simon R. Green, Ursala K. LeGuin though not any of her recent work, Larry Niven, Max Brooks, and Charles Stross.

Comment: @robertcday - If you don't mind, I'm going to edit a few of these factoids into your actual post to support your (already strong) answer.  I'm also going to ask for this comments thread to be deleted, it's become clear Ash is just trolling us.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris. I had half a mind to tell you yesterday that he was trolling and not to take the bait, but I have a *don't get involved* approach to these sorts of thing. You sure it's worth making the effort to add in comments? After all, the question is on hold.

Comment: @robertcday  Sure, on hold questions still appear in the archives and in searches.

Answer (score 3):

- Christopher Paolini - *Eragon* (Bestseller.)
- Richard Paul Evans - *The Christmas Box* (#1 Bestseller.)
- Mark Danielewski - *House of Leaves* (cult classic, initially self-published
  online, it was issued in print by Pantheon Books.)
- Catherynne M. Valente - *The Girl Who Circumnavigated Fairyland in a Ship of Her Own Making* (Inaugurated a best-selling series.  Initially self-published online, later issued in print by Feiwel & Friends.)
- Becky Chambers - *The Long Way to a Small, Angry Planet* (Critically acclaimed SF novel.  Originally self-published it via a Kickstarter campaign; it was subsequently re-published by Hodder & Stoughton.)

It's worth noting that while critical reaction to these books has been mixed (mostly bad for Paolini and Evans, mostly good for the other three), they all share one important trait --**their authors were all exceptionally good at promoting their own work.**  As I've said repeatedly, that's the one most important trait for a successful self-publisher.

In point of fact, the three internet-published authors all successfully built a community of engaged fans *as the book was being written*.  That certainly seems like a new model for a successful self-publisher, the modern equivalent of the newspaper serials that built Dickens' fame.

Comment: Upvoted for House of Leaves